# Can't Access Object Variables In PHP

Tags: php, object, stdclass

For some reason when I print_r a variable containing an object I get data. However when I try to access each item using the `->` notation it says it is `NULL`.

Here is the `print_r` dump of `$user_data`:

```
STDCLASS OBJECT ( 
    [UACC_ID] => 6 
    [UACC_GROUP_FK] => 1 
    [UACC_EMAIL] => xxx@GMAIL.COM 
    [UACC_USERNAME] => xxxx 
    [UACC_PASSWORD] => $2A$08$CLSxxxxxxEOS7D2NDCSDD3P6A6 
    [UACC_IP_ADDRESS] => xx.xxx.xx.65 
    [UACC_SALT] => C64JYWY7ZS
    [UACC_ACTIVATION_TOKEN] => 
    [UACC_FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_TOKEN] => 
    [UACC_FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_EXPIRE] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
    [UACC_UPDATE_EMAIL_TOKEN] => 
    [UACC_UPDATE_EMAIL] => 
    [UACC_ACTIVE] => 1 
    [UACC_SUSPEND] => 0 
    [UACC_FAIL_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS] => 0 
    [UACC_FAIL_LOGIN_IP_ADDRESS] => 
    [UACC_DATE_FAIL_LOGIN_BAN] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
    [UACC_DATE_LAST_LOGIN] => 2013-05-05 07:18:34 
    [UACC_DATE_ADDED] => 2013-04-28 09:34:39 
    [UGRP_ID] => 1 
    [UGRP_NAME] => PUBLIC 
    [UGRP_DESC] => PUBLIC USER : HAS NO ADMIN ACCESS RIGHTS. 
    [UGRP_ADMIN] => 0 
    [UPRO_ID] => 6 
    [UPRO_UACC_FK] => 6 
    [UPRO_COMPANY] => 
    [UPRO_FIRST_NAME] => xxxx 
    [UPRO_LAST_NAME] => xxxxx 
    [UPRO_PHONE] => 01392 
    [UPRO_NEWSLETTER] => 0 
    [UADD_ID] => 
    [UADD_UACC_FK] => 
    [UADD_ALIAS] => 
    [UADD_RECIPIENT] => 
    [UADD_PHONE] => 
    [UADD_COMPANY] => 
    [UADD_ADDRESS_01] => 
    [UADD_ADDRESS_02] => 
    [UADD_CITY] => 
    [UADD_COUNTY] => 
    [UADD_POST_CODE] => 
    [UADD_COUNTRY] => 
)
```

However, when I try this I get `NULL`:

```
var_dump($user_data->UACC_ID);
```

I can't seem to echo anything by using the notation `$user_data->UACC_EMAIL` etc. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all. It appears the output was being converted to ALLCAPS in CSS and so I didn't realise that the library actually uses the lower case variants.

Thanks.

---

Comment: If there wasn't such key as `UACC_ID` you will get an error trying to access `$user_data->UACC_ID` - that means that something maybe override the value - can you post the full code ?

Comment: The only code I have is the below, I don't understand why it doesn't work:                                $user_data = $this->flexi_auth->get_user_by_id()->row();
                print_r($user_data);
                //var_dump($user_data);
                var_dump($user_data->UACC_ID);

Comment: show the result of `var_dump(serialize($user_data))`

Comment: [There's quite obviously another error somewhere in your code, as it works fine - check out this demo](http://codepad.org/jMYy5Zof).

Comment: Neither `print_r` nor `var_dump` turn output to ALLCAPS, post the actual output without embellishing it. Edit: [since you're using Flexi Auth, the column is named `uacc_id`, not `UACC_ID`](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/user_guide/user_account_config).

Comment: DCoder is completely right - are you **sure** it isn't `$user_data->uacc_id` or `$user_data->uacc_ID` etc., and you either have a CSS transform or turn it all into uppercase using an output buffer and `strtoupper`?

Comment: Please show code for object and how you're accessing its members. Then it would be a lot easier to check what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One possibilities, however strange, is that the object has a __get function defined to capture and return null on internal private data points, to prevent php from throwing fatal "cant access private" errors if you try accessing any data directly.

so, yes, UACC_ID exists, and is in there, but is being intercepted.